# @Autowired doesn't work with FlatFileItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to inject my FlatFileItemWriter in a processor, but i get always the same exception.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:993)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
... 56 more
```

My configuration is the following. I declared my FlatFileItemWriter in this way:

```
    <bean id="myWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter" />
```

Then i enabled the bean autoscan and the annotation config in this way:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myCompany.batch"/>
```

and finally I try to Autowired the bean

```
@Component
public class GsLetturaProcessor implements ItemProcessor<GsLettura,GsLettura>,Costanti{

@Autowired
FlatFileItemWriter writer;

}
```

Usually I'm to able to define a bean in the application context and inject it in another bean. Why it doesn't work in this case? I thought that maybe the problem is that FlatFileItemWriter use a generics. Where am I doing wrong?

**Update1**

[image]

My bean befinition is in job-context.xml while the latter is in the context.xml

Comment: Please show us the complete configuration.

Comment: What do you want to see exactly?

Comment: Are both those snippets in the same context configuration file?

Comment: I updated my question, these are used from spring-web-admin. I'm using the sample in the lattercase I just override some components

Comment: How are `jobs-context.xml` and `context.xml` related?

Comment: Can you explain me better what do you mean with **How are jobs-context.xml and context.xml related**?

Comment: Why do you expect a bean in one context to be available to a bean in another context? Are you importing one in the other? Are you making one a parent of the other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64043/discussion-between-skizzo-and-sotirios-delimanolis).